# Mule db:parameterized-query file attribute

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When I set the `file` attribute `of db:parameterized-query` through AnyPoint, I get a path that is local to my machine. I have the file in `src/main/resources` in my project, but I can't figure out how to reference it or through the classpath relatively. I've tried stuff like `classpath:myquery.sql`, but I keep getting `Unable to read query from file`.

Here's my configuration:

```
<db:template-query name="my-query-template" doc:name="Template Query">
    <db:parameterized-query file="how-do-i-get-to/myquery.sql"/>
</db:template-query>
```

How can I load the file from the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

By default when we choose template from file, the Location will be filled with the absolute path. It refers to local machine, e.g.: `C:\MuleSoft\Project\src\main\resources\myquery.sql`

To load file from the classpath, regardless where will it be deployed, then just keep the main path: `<db:parameterized-query file="src\main\resources\myquery.sql"/>`

Comment: I think your suggestion is incorrect, because when we use maven to generate artifact, this final artifact does not have a folder src/main/resources inside!!! All .class, .xml and files inside src/main/resources are moved to /classes folder.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
${app.home}/classes/myquery.sql
```

As all the files placed into src/main/resources get copied into classes folder while building the zip. 
Here app.home refers the root location of your build, you don't need to create this variable explicitly.

Hope this help!!